# Protecting page using Next 13 wih AppRoutes, Typescript and Firebase

Tags: typescript, firebase, routes, next.js13, next-auth

I'm using Next 13 with Typescript and Firebase and I need to protect my routes. Basically, I just want the user who is not logged in to be redirected to /login and not be allowed to access another route. While the user who is logged in does not see /login, but can access the other routes. I can do this with PageRoutes or React, but I'm having a lot of difficulty doing this with Next AppRoutes, can anyone help me?

My project structure is:

[image]

I created a component ProtectedRoutes.tsx:

```
"use client"

import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation';
import { useAuth } from '@/hooks/useAuth';

const ProtectedRoutes = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
  const { isLoggedIn, isLoading } = useAuth();
  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isLoading && !isLoggedIn) {
      router.push('/login');
    }
  }, [isLoggedIn, isLoading, router]);

  return <>{children}</>;
};

export default ProtectedRoutes;
```

and my src/app/layout.tsx:

```
import { AuthProvider } from '@/hooks/useAuth';
import '../styles/globals.css'
import type { Metadata } from 'next'
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google'

import { ToastContainer } from "react-toastify";

import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css";
import ProtectedRoutes from '@/components/ProtectedRoutes';

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: 'Proposals Mayara Dev',
  description: 'Proposals System Mayara Becker Dev',
}

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body suppressHydrationWarning={true} className={inter.className}>
        <ProtectedRoutes>
          <AuthProvider>
            {children}
            <ToastContainer position='bottom-right' />
          </AuthProvider>
        </ProtectedRoutes>
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

My project is here:
https://proposals-mayarabecker-dev.vercel.app/

You can test, user: admin@admin.com
password: 12345678

My source code is:
https://bitbucket.org/eltin182/proposals-mayarabecker-dev/src/main/frontend/

The problem is: when I type /login while not logged in, it quickly shows my home page and then redirects to /login, this is not correct. While if the user is logged in and types /login it will show the login form even though they are already logged in, which is not correct.

I created ProtectRoutes.tsx and included it in the main layout of the application, it is almost working, but it is still not protecting the page completely, because when the user is not logged in and tries to access /, he will be able to see the home page for a while. brief moment. And also when logged in, it will access /login, which doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: I also have this same question did you get any answer related this?

Comment: @alpha_N1618 nothing yet